# Fatal Error When Rendering With A VBO LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, vbo

I am very new to using VBOs to render data and while I was trying to draw a cube I got a pretty bad error.

#### A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000069198aa0, pid=11936, tid=7072

This makes the program crash. I noticed that when I commented out the render method in my code the error went away, but I can't seem to find the source of the error since I'm new to VBOs. The code is below, any help is appreciated.

## Code

```
package engine;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBindBuffer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBufferData;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glGenBuffers;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;

public class Render{

    private int amountOfVerts = 4;
    private int vertexSize = 3;
    private int colorSize = 1;
    private FloatBuffer vertData, colorData;
    private int handle, colorHandle;

    public Render() {
        vertData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVerts * vertexSize);
        vertData.put(new float[]{0f,0f,0f, 100f,0f,0f, 100f,100f,0f, 0f,100f,0f});
        vertData.flip();

        colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(amountOfVerts * colorSize);
        colorData.put(new float[]{1,0,0});
        colorData.flip();

        handle = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle); //sets the current buffer to this
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // fills the new buffer / stores data
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbinds

        colorHandle = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle); //sets the current buffer to this
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, GL_STATIC_DRAW); // fills the new buffer / stores data
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // unbinds
    }

    public void render(){
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle);
        GL11.glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorHandle);
        GL11.glColorPointer(colorSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, amountOfVerts);
        GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    }


}
```

## EDIT

```
package engine;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_MODELVIEW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_PROJECTION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

public class Screen {

    private Render r;
    private Camera c;
    private int w,h;

    public Screen() {
        init();
        r = new Render();
        c = new Camera(new Vector3f(0,0,0), 5f, 0.15f);
        gameLoop();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Screen s = new Screen();
    }

    public void init(){
        try{
            Display.setDisplayModeAndFullscreen(Display.getDesktopDisplayMode());
            w = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getWidth();
            h = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode().getHeight();
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
            Display.create();
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluPerspective(30f, w / h, 0.003f, 1000f);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            Mouse.setGrabbed(true);

        }catch (LWJGLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void gameLoop(){
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)){
                System.exit(0);
                Display.destroy();
            }
            render();
            update();
            glLoadIdentity();
            c.lookThroughCamera();
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        Display.destroy();

    }

    public void update(){
        c.update();
        c.mouseX = Mouse.getDX();
        c.mouseY = -Mouse.getDY();
        c.addYaw(c.mouseX * c.sensetivity);
        c.addPitch(c.mouseY * c.sensetivity);
    }

    public void render(){
        r.render();
    }
}
```

Comment: when did you initialized Render clasS?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin If you check the edit I have placed the rest of the code. It's initialized in the constructor of the Screen class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [glColorPointer:](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml)

```
size: Specifies the number of components per color. Must be 3 or 4
```

Changing your `colorSize` to 3 and adding the needed floats to the color buffer should fix your problem.

```
colorData.put(new float[]{0f,0f,0f, 1f,0f,0f, 1f,1f,0f, 0f,1f,0f});
```

Comment: That did the trick! I would have never thought that something so simple would have caused that error. Thanks!